# Adding onPause/onResume to a Youtube video within an Ionic 2 page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a small issue I need fixing on a very basic demo Android app in Ionic 2.

When a Youtube video plays on the Homepage, if you press the power button or the phone goes into sleep/lock mode the Youtube video continues playing. This issue causes Google to reject the app in the Play Store as they do not allow this to happen on Youtube embeds.

So I need to add some code to pause the video if the state changes and resume when it wakes up again.

The feature I need to add seems to be called onPause and onResume but I am unsure how and where to add the code to get this feature working with this custom Youtube code.

Here are the files in a repo, and APK (only 3mb) just a change to the homepage on a blank ionic 2 install, where you can see the issue in action.

[Github Repo](https://github.com/e1463926/youtubeion2/tree/master/src/pages/home)
[APK in Github](https://github.com/e1463926/youtubeion2/blob/master/yt-single.apk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd avoid the issues you are having by going straight for the Youtube Video Plugin, you can see the Preview video on how to install it here

https://www.udemy.com/master-ionic-3-with-ionic-native-and-cordova-integrations

NODE

```
ionic cordova add https://github.com/JonSmart/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer

npm install @ionic-native/youtube-video-player
```

APP.MODULE.TS

```
import {YoutubeVideoPlayer} from '@ionic-native/youtube-video-player'
```

add to list of providers YoutubeVideoPlayer

HOME.TS

```
import {YoutubeVideoPlayer} from '@ionic-native/youtube-video-player'
```

Under export class

```
constructor (private videoPlayer: YoutubeVideoPlayer ) {}

playVideo(video: Video) {
    this.videoPlayer.openVideo(video.videoId)
}
```

API Key required for Android
Search for "Youtube Data API Overview"

config.xml ("under allow-intent")

Answer (score 6):

I would add a comment to add to what n00b said, but I don't have 50 reputation points yet. To add to noobs answer and give an extra hint. Please mark n00b as the correct answer as he posted first.

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class page {
    currentVideoSource: SafeResourceUrl;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        this.currentVideoSource = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("youtubeurl");
    }
```

now src should work with something like the following in the iframe

```
[src]="currentVideoSource";
```

Comment: Almost there, the error has gone. But failing to load the video. The videos load for each product using {{product.video}} in a previous Ionic 1. here is the code in a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/HrZVaz34XxBc2s03Lu8G?p=catalogue

Comment: Are you having more trouble with this one? Try this... instead of {{product.video}} like you are doing currently, ... Try this.currentVideoSource = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(product.video); I can't say for sure if that will work because I can't test it, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

you should add that URL to Angular2 DomSanitizer exception list. What you see is a security feature of Angular2 that prevents people load malicious URLs in y our app.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html

Comment: Thanks, almost there. Just an issue targeting the video, see above

Answer (score 0):

From this [blog post](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/handling-apache-cordova-events-ionicframework/),

It says you can make use of Apache Cordova event listeners.

> Apache Cordova events require no additional plugin installation for IonicFramework.
>
> To register an event we must do so in our $ionicPlatform.ready() method.

Some of the Listeners are

**resume**  - The resume event fires when the native platform pulls the application out from the background.

**pause**   - The event fires when an application is put into the background.

**online**  - This event fires when an application goes online, and the device becomes connected to the Internet.

**offline** - The event fires when an application goes offline, and the device is not connected to the Internet.

In your JS file, add

```
angular.module(...).run(function($ionicPlatform){
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
           document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
              //Code to pause the video
           }, false);
     });
```

For a full list of supported events, Refer to the [Apache Cordova official website](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#pause)

Comment: Thanks Sagar V. This is for Ionic 1 though(Ionic 2 with Typescript) and need to know the exact code to use within the files shown in Github repo.